# Best way to make this transaction?

Tags: paypal, payment

I have to pay through a bank transfer or physical money to third party, and I have my money like this:

- Paypal account
- Payoneer account.

For what I understand, I can't wire transfer from neither of them to a another bank account, correct me if I'm wrong though, I can only transfer from Paypal to Payoneer, since they are both linked.

So if I understand correctly, the only way to do this would be to physically extract the money, right?, any other alternative?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Payoneer and PayPal both allow you to connect your bank account to withdraw funds, that is likely your best option

Comment: Ok so the only way would be to physically withdraw and then to pay also with physical money. Another alternative would be for him to create a Paypal account and then to link his bank account right?. That would probably be the easiest and fastest way.

Comment: What do you mean physical? It doesnt have to be cash they can send you bank transfers. But yes, you can do that

Comment: You said "withdraw funds" which means to have the cash in my hand. Besides no-one is transferring money, I am the one transferring.

Comment: I think the confusion is that the OP doesn't seem to have a bank account of his own, so he has nothing to connect to.  Is that correct @Artemix ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is solved, I just withdrew money from the ATM and paid that way.